# Como posso fazer um SELECT para mostrar apenas os primeiros 4 registos

Tags: php

Bom, como a minha dúvida não se enquadra completamente na pergunta, vou continuar a pergunta por aqui.

Pretendo fazer um select, que me mostre apenas os primeiros 4 registos do banco de dados.

E de seguida pretendo fazer outro select diferente, que me mostre do 5º registo ao 9 registo do banco de dados.

Como poderia fazer isso?

Obrigado.

Comment: Você quer fazer uma paginação de registros?

Comment: Isso mesmo! Pretendia fazer algo semelhante.

Comment: Qual o banco???

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o comando `LIMIT` para definir a quantidade de registros.

Consulta com os primeiros 4 registros (exibindo os próximos 4 registros a partir do indice zero):

```
SELECT * FROM tabela LIMIT 0, 4
```

Consulta do 5º registo ao 9º registo (exibindo os próximos 4 registros a partir do indice 5 a fim de mostrar até o registro 9 ):

```
SELECT * FROM tabela LIMIT 5, 4
```